# adobe air mobile locate people or interesting places

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, google-maps-api-3, air

I am going to do an app capable of locating people nearby or interesting place. I don't need to show the map. Is it possible to achieve. I know we can grab the map position from air in mobile. Can we send this position to somewhere to get those information i need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

"The GoogleMaps API for ActionScript 3.0 was deprecated in August of 2011 "forcing" developers to use different methods for integrating maps in mobile and desktop application projects"